# shiny: no response when switching between menuSubItems after first clicked actionButton

Tags: shiny

By using shiny and shinydashboard package,I have create a group of menuItems and menuSubItems as well as the coresponding tabItems, and there is a conditionalPanel with different input parameters for each menuSubItems,
and an actionButton for different analysing and ploting task,now it works before the actionButton is clicked, that is, the conditionalPanel changed when switching between menuSubItems,and it also works well for the first time actionButton is clicked, that is it show a plot html as expected, but after the first clicked of actionButton, the conditionalPanel no longer changed as before when switching between menuSubItems, it seems that the menuSubItems can not update when clicked by mouse in the ui, How can I fix it?

the programs is so long that, I can only paste a piece of them as follows:
the myshinyOutput is a selfdefined function for creating a html with input parameters.

```
    server=function(input,output,session,dir="D:/ShinyServer"){
      observeEvent(input$sidebarmenu,{
        js$collapse("parbox")
        if(input$sidebarmenu=="a") {
          selmets=c("a"="a","b"="b")
          selstatistic=c("stat"="mean","statb"="anomaly")
          updateSelectInput(session,inputId="selmets",choices=selmets,selected=c("t","r","s"))
          updateSelectInput(session,inputId="selstatistic",label="sel:",choices=selstatistic,selected="mean")
          updateDateRangeInput(session,inputId="dateRange",start=inputdateRange$start,end=inputdateRange$end)
          updateSelectInput(session,inputId="selstationoption",selected="all")
          updateSelectInput(session,inputId="saveres",selected="plot")
          updateTextInput(session,inputId="compyear",value="")   
        }else if(input$sidebarmenu=="b") {
          selmets=c("sunshine","fog","haze","hail","snow","snowdepth")
          updateSelectInput(session,inputId="selmets",choices=selmets,selected=c("sunshine"))
          updateDateRangeInput(session,inputId="dateRange",start=inputdateRange$start,end=inputdateRange$end)
          updateSelectInput(session,inputId="saveres",selected="plot")
        }     
      })

      htmlvalues=reactive({
        if(input$runButton == 0)
        {
          return()
        }
       #isolate({
          input$runButton
          renderUI({isolate(myshinyOutput(input,rootdir=dir,htmlwidth=2000)$html)})
       #})
      })


      downloadlisthtml=reactive({
        if(input$runButton == 0)
        {
          return()
        }
       #isolate({
          input$runButton
          renderUI({isolate(gendownloadlisthtml())})
       #})
      })  

      observeEvent(input$runButton,
                   {
                     js$collapse("parbox")
                     if(input$sidebarmenu=='grd'){

                     }else{
                       output[[paste(shinymodulesub(input$sidebarmenu),"_html",sep="")]]=htmlvalues()
                       output[[paste(shinymodulesub(input$sidebarmenu),"download_html",sep="")]]=downloadlisthtml()
                     }    
                   })
    }


    # > sessionInfo()
    # R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
    # Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
    # Running under: Windows 7 (build 7600)
    # 
    # 
    # other attached packages:
    #   [1] shinydashboard_0.5.3
    # [2] shiny_1.0.0         
    # 
    # loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    #   [1] R6_2.1.1        htmltools_0.3.5
    # [3] tools_3.3.2     Rcpp_0.12.9    
    # [5] digest_0.6.8    xtable_1.7-4   
    # [7] httpuv_1.3.3    mime_0.3
```

Comment: Try using 'bsButton' from the package 'shinyBS’. The you can update your button value using the function `updateButton` function. Refer to [this](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Buttons.html#bsButton) and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyBS/shinyBS.pdf) link.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.